# FabricJS strokeWidth - strokeDashArray Bug?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm drawing a dashed line and a dashed rect in fabricjs, but there is an issue when setting the strokeWidth too high for the line/rect to draw the strokeDashArray properly.

Example:
if `strokeDashArray: [10,2]` and the `strokeWidh: 1` everything's fine, but if I set `strokeWidh: 5` the line/rect isn't dashed anymore.

I found out, that setting strokeLineCap: 'square' messes it up, but i don't understand why

Fiddle - Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kesh23/bf56wtkc/)

Would appreciate any kind of help :D

Comment: I made a more clear answer for everyone, if possible accept it.

Answer (score 0):

asturur (contributor fabric.js) wrote this explanation:

> Is not messed up. is how square workds. you have to make strokeDash
>   with more space between "black and white".

Comment: a reference to the argument would be really appreciated, come on, do you really think this is a good answer?

Comment: Of course this was not an answer. It was a comment on the github issue. i added a clarifying answer for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the below screenshot the line cap modify the line visual length.

[image]

While the virtual length is the same for every of them, every line gets a strokewidth/2 piece attached to the end and start.
So with a strokeWidth of 5, and a additional piece of 2.5, you are eating away your strokedash of [10, 2] where 2 is the white space between dashes.